# ESLint: 'chrome' is not defined (no-undef)

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension, eslint

I added ESLint to my chrome extension project. I am using chrome API which starts with `chrome.`, but obviously eslint points on it as error.

I suppose it should be something like:

```
"env": {
  "browser": true,
  "chrome": true,
  "es6": true
},
```

but apparently it's not.

Comment: There is no chrome env I don't think. Have you tried `/* global chrome */`?

Comment: `webextensions: true`

Answer (score 107):

You need to add:

```
"env": {
    // ...
    "webextensions": true
}
```

to your `.eslintrc.json` file or eslint configuration in general.

Comment: The "webextensions" key in eslintConfig doesn't work for me.. Here's my eslintConfig from package.json: `"eslintConfig": { "extends": "react-app", "env": {"webextensions": true}},` Any idea why ?

Comment: Can you add to `env`, `"browser": true,` as well? Next to webextensions.

Comment: Still no luck... `"eslintConfig": { "extends": "react-app", "env": { "webextensions": true, "browser": true } },` so far the only solution that works for me is adding `/* global chrome */` at the top of my js files that use "chrome".

Comment: Make sure you're using at least ESLint 1.7.0

Answer (score 10):

You can add this in your eslint config file to add a global variable

```
"globals": {
    "chrome": true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: In [`create-react-app v4.0.0`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v4.0.0/CHANGELOG.md), the `EXTEND_ESLINT` flag is no longer required to customize the ESLint config, so the following answer should not be necessary past version 4.0.0.

> We've also upgraded `eslint-plugin-hooks` to version 4.0.0 and removed the `EXTEND_ESLINT` flag as it is no longer required to customize the ESLint config.

---

I am using `create-react-app` and found that in addition to defining:

```yaml
# This is YAML btw
env:
  # ...
  webextensions: true
```

in my `eslint` config (which adds `chrome` as a global), I also had to set the `EXTEND_ESLINT` environment variable for `create-react-app` to `true`. [Docs here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/).

There are a few different ways of setting this environment variable. For example, you can create a `.env` file in the root of your project folder with the content:

```
EXTEND_ESLINT=true
```

From the documentation, I believe this an experimental feature, but it provides your `eslint` config to the `eslint-loader`. Prior to setting enabling this, I had to manually comment the

```
/* global chrome */
```

in each file, since the build process was not using my `eslint` config and therefore not recognizing that I set `chrome` to be a global.

And although this question does not mention `create-react-app`, I'm sure lots of people will come to this question with the same circumstance as myself.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments there is no `chrome` environment, you can find more information about the configurable environments in the eslint [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#specifying-environments).

You can specify globals for each file as a top line comment, or in your configuration file, see [specifying global](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals). You can also write your custom Eslint Chrome plugin that sets the globals and parser options(that is what an environment does for you) and import that into your config file.